# wxPython class doesnt show in window

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython, wxwidgets

So i created a class that runs a big calculation in a seperet thread.

This is what i expected to see:

[image: Expected]

And this is what i do see:

[image: What i should see]

This is the frame class

```
class ThreadFrame(wx.Frame):

def __init__(self,parent=None):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent=parent)
    self.frame = wx.Frame(None, title='Bitte Warten',style=wx.FRAME_NO_TASKBAR)
    self.frame.SetSize(500,100)
    self.panel=wx.Panel(self.frame)
    self.parent=parent
    self.WaitLbl=wx.StaticText(self.panel,-1)
    self.WaitLbl.SetLabel('Geotags werden ausgelesen und abgerufen.')
    self.progress = wx.Gauge(self.panel,size=(500,30), range=self.parent.list_ctrl.GetItemCount())
    self.btn = wx.Button(self.panel,label='Abbrechen')
    self.btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnExit)

    self.Sizer=wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)          

    #Add Widgets LeftSizer
    self.Sizer.Add(self.WaitLbl,0,wx.ALL|wx.CENTER,5)
    self.Sizer.Add(self.progress,0,wx.ALL,5)
    self.Sizer.Add(self.btn,0,wx.ALL|wx.CENTER,5)


    self.panel.SetSizer(self.Sizer)
    self.Sizer.Fit(self.panel)
    self.panel.Layout()            
    self.Centre()            



    #Bind to the progress event issued by the thread
    self.Bind(EVT_PROGRESS_EVENT, self.OnProgress)
    #Bind to Exit on frame close
    #self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnExit)
    self.Show()

    self.mythread = TestThread(self.frame, self.parent)
    #Enable the GUI to be responsive by briefly returning control to the main App
    while self.mythread.isAlive():
        time.sleep(0.1)
        wx.GetApp().Yield()
        continue

    try:
        self.OnExit(None)
    except:
        pass

def OnProgress(self, event):
    self.progress.SetValue(event.count)
    #or for indeterminate progress
    #self.progress.Pulse()

def OnExit(self, event):
    if self.mythread.isAlive():
        print('Thread lebt noch')
        self.mythread.terminate() # Shutdown the thread
        print('Thread wird beendet')
        self.mythread.join() # Wait for it to finish

    self.Close()
```

And this is the thread where the calculation is running

```
class TestThread(Thread):
def __init__(self,parent_target,toplevel):
    Thread.__init__(self)
    self.parent = toplevel
    self.ownparent=parent_target
    self.stopthread = False
    self.start()    # start the thread

def run(self):
    print('Thread gestartet')
    i=0
    while self.stopthread == False:        
           #if calculation is not finished:
                #do calculation and count i one up
                evt = progress_event(count=i)

                    #Send back current count for the progress bar
                try:
                    wx.PostEvent(self.ownparent, evt)

                except: # The parent frame has probably been destroyed

                    self.terminate()
                i=i+1
        else:
            print('Thread Terminated')
            self.terminate()


def terminate(self):
    self.stopthread = True
```

And this is how i call the class from my main programm:

```
frame=ThreadFrame(self)
```

The main program also has a frame open. So this is a frame which is opend and then starts a thread which does calculation and then stops. 
I think thats all that is to know. I replaced the caluclation with speudo code because my brain hurts and i cant come up with a plachold right now. But i feel like between all the fiting and sizers and panels and frames i went somewhere wrong. And i totaly dont look through all of this stuff at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So im not sure what caused the problem. I started from scratch and now it works. This time i didnt use a new frame because the class itself is allready a frame.

```
class GeoThreadFrame(wx.Frame):

def __init__(self, radsteuer):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent=radsteuer.frame,style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE | wx.STAY_ON_TOP|wx.FRAME_NO_TASKBAR)
    panel = wx.Panel(self)
    self.SetWindowStyle(wx.FRAME_NO_TASKBAR|wx.STAY_ON_TOP)

    self.progress = wx.Gauge(panel,size=(300,30), pos=(10,50), range=radsteuer.list_ctrl.GetItemCount())

    self.btn = wx.Button(panel,label='Abbrechen', size=(200,30), pos=(10,10))
    self.btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnExit)
    panel.Center()
    #Bind to the progress event issued by the thread
    self.Bind(EVT_PROGRESS_EVENT, self.OnProgress)
    #Bind to Exit on frame close
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnExit)
    self.Center()
    self.Show()

    self.mythread = GeoLocationThread(self, radsteuer)
    #Enable the GUI to be responsive by briefly returning control to the main App
    while self.mythread.isAlive():            
        #time.sleep(0.1)
        wx.GetApp().Yield()
        continue

    try:
        self.OnExit(None)
    except:
        pass

def OnProgress(self, event):
    self.progress.SetValue(event.count)
    #or for indeterminate progress
    #self.progress.Pulse()

def OnExit(self, event):

    if self.mythread.isAlive():            
        self.mythread.terminate() # Shutdown the thread            
        #self.mythread.join(3) # Wait for it to finish            
    self.Destroy()

class GeoLocationThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self,parent_target,mainparent):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.parent = parent_target
        self.mainparent=mainparent
        self.stopthread = False
        self.start()    # start the thread

    def run(self):
        # A loop that will run for 5 minutes then terminate
        i=0
        while self.stopthread == False:


            if i < self.mainparent.list_ctrl.GetItemCount():
                self.calculation(i)
                evt = progress_event(count=i)
                i=i+1
                #Send back current count for the progress bar
                try:
                    wx.PostEvent(self.parent, evt)
                except: # The parent frame has probably been destroyed
                    self.terminate()
            else:
                self.terminate()

    def terminate(self):

        self.stopthread = True

    def calculate(self,i):
        #your calculation here
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you show doesn't seem to correspond to the screenshots. Whatever problem with the layout you might have, you should still have "Bitte warten" in the frame title, but your screenshot doesn't even show this. Either you're not executing the code you show at all, or you create some other frame elsewhere in your code which you see here. Or, of course, you've uploaded a wrong screenshot or code version. But something just doesn't fit here.

Comment: This is indeed a second window im opening. Is that a problem? The Parent that i give has another window with his own panel and sizers. But those work fine.

Comment: @Odatas it's not a problem to have multiple windows. It is a problem that your frame title doesn't show "Bitte warten". I.e. this is just not the right frame.